How to require a State run on a separate minion without orchestration?
I am working on salt states to fail multiple applications over from one prod cluster to another. I want to run 2 salt states (stop_service and iisreset). stop_service will run only on servers on clusterA and clusterB, iisreset will run on all servers in clusterA, clusterB and clusterC but depends on stop_service completing successfully in clusterA & clusterB. How do I create this kind of dependency for states running on different servers.
Note: I am aware 'salt orchestrate" can do this, but in our salt environment, we do not have any access to the salt masters (we can only run state.apply or salt-call on minions). So looking for some "hacky" alternative way to achieve this.
{% set cluster = grains['prodcluster'] %}
{% if cluster in ["clusterA","clusterB"] %}
stop_service:
  service.dead:
    - name: my_service
{% endif %}

reset iis: # this needs to run on all 3 clusters only after the above state has completed successfully.
  cmd.run:
    - name: iisreset

How do I make cluster C not to run iisreset until after clusterA and clusterB services are stopped?

When you say you don't have access, does that include not being able to set up reactors or authorise remote callers to trigger orchestration?

Yes, we also can't set up reactors. Basically cannot do anything that requires adding or modifying a config on the salt masters. The /srv/salt/ directory is ported to source control, and we use ext_pillars. I am restricted to placing configs in pillars or /srv/salt/ and/or on the minions.

Technically you can use the pillar templating to run whatever you want on the master, but you might get in trouble for that.

I've added more details to my answer.

Without access to the Salt master there is no way to do this (which would be using an orchestration, as you say).
A "hack" could be to do the remote call with SSH or similar instead of Salt.
{% for cluster in ["clusterA", "clusterB"] %}
stop service on {{ cluster }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ssh root@{{ cluster }} salt-call service.stop my_service
    - require_in:
      - reset iis
{% endfor %}

reset iis:
  cmd.run:
    - name: iisreset

You can also use Salt to set up the ssh key authentication, but you would need orchestration to ensure it works in the right order the first time.
An even nastier hack is to use the pillar templating to call orchestration, but you may struggle to control when it happens.
{% do salt["saltutil.runner"]("state.orchestrate", arg=["_orch.my_service"]) %}

If your master is not configured securely, you could also edit the configuration with the same trick to set up a reactor or enable peer communication.
